# nohup command has different kill /dev/null

Tags: linux

I have a shell script runProgram.sh which starts a batch-processing job and sends email with output after the job is finished. I used nohup to run it in the background. it works fine.

nohup ./runProgram.sh &

The drawback is nohup.out file that slows down my system and even kills other running processes. So I changed nohup as below which kill nohup.out (I don't need it at all).

nohup ./runProgram.sh > /dev/null &

Now, the problem is that an email with a previous-run output is sent as soon as the job being kicked off. The current output email is not sent at the end of the job.

I did search around and couldn't find answers. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
DZ

I have a beginner in Unix. I used nohup to execute a shell script which basically executes a job and sends an email after the job done. It works fine. But when I redirect nohup.out to /dev/null. The email will be sent at the bigining of kicking off the job instead of the end of it.

nohup execute-job

Comment: Post your script, or at least the part of it that sends mail.

Comment: How exactly is the batch processing job started?

Comment: This is part of script to start a job and send email: